# ¿Cómo pasar (castear, "igualar") parte de un búfer de datos a una variable flotante?

Tags: c, embebido

buen día.

Tengo una variable para latitud, la cual la estoy almacenando en un buffer de tipo uint64_t y se va llenando de manera serial

```c
    volatile uint64_t Latitude =    (((uint64_t)BufferTmp[22]<<56)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[21]<<48)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[20]<<40)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[19]<<32)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[18]<<24)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[17]<<16)|
                ((uint64_t)BufferTmp[16]<<8)|
                (uint64_t)BufferTmp[15]);
```

Para mostrarla, únicamente dispongo de 32 bits, por lo que he optado por realizar un casteo a tipo float.
He probado distintos tipos de casteo, pero ninguno me brinda el resultado que deseo, algunos ni siquiera muestran valores.
Realicé una copia de la variable y finalmente la parseo en 4 bytes y la muestro.

```c
memcpy((u08 *)&data, (u08 *)&Latitude, sizeof(data));
INFO_GPS.Latitude.total= (s32)(data);
```

También probé con la fórmula de la mantissa, exponente y signo, pero no me arroja resultados. 
¿Alguien sabe qué podría hacer? ¿O cuál es la manera correcta de pasar esta variable?

[image: Esta imagen proviene de la hoja de datos del producto que me arroja la latitud]

**Actualización: ** He declarado la típica estructura para implementar el estándar IEEE754, con las 3 distintas distribuciones para un double. Sin embargo los datos siguen sin aparecer correctamente.

Comment: La [latitud](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitud) tiene sólo 180 valores posibles (de -90 a 90) ¿Por qué estás usando un entero de 64 bits sin signo?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster la razón es que el dispositivo que me provee ese valor me lo da en formato de 64 bits, por eso de la precisión.

Comment: ¿Y qué formato tiene ese valor? Piensa que un entero de 64bits puede almacenar más de 18 trillones de valores ¿A qué corresponde cada unidad del `uint64_t`? ¿Una billonésima de grado de latitud? Piensa que una millonésima de grado de latitud son unos 10cm. Por otro lado ¿Qué [extremidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) tienen los datos?

Comment: El dispositivo envía los bytes en little endian y tienes razón, la precisión es una exageración.

Comment: Por lo que estoy viendo en tu última edición, la latitud no viene en 64 bits si no como los 8 primeros bytes de un búfer de 23. Tampoco es un valor entero si no un `double`.

Comment: Es correcto... El problema es que también he cambiado los uint64 por ´´´double´´´ y no logro hallar el correcto procesamiento, no sé si en el memcpy también suceda algo, he probado con hacer el típico cast rápido de declarar un float y asignarle el valor casteado del double... Y nada me funciona

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para que refleje la duda actual: ¿Cómo pasar parte de un búfer de datos a una variable?

Comment: En linux, existe un archivo `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ieee754.h` que define el tipo `union ieee754_double { }` en varios *endian* (mira los `#ifdef` ). Tómalo como ejemplo y haz tus pruebas. Si **ninguna** combinación te sirve ... mal asunto. ¿ Seguro que el dispositivo envía los datos como `double` ?

Comment: No me ha servido ninguna combinación para double

Answer (score 3):

Según veo en tu pregunta, dispones de un búfer de 23 bytes que contiene tres datos de tipo `double` en las posiciones 0, 8 y 16:

---

[image]

---

Si tu sistema tiene la misma arquitectura de extremidad que el origen de datos, sería muy fácil leer la información:

```
double latitude = .0, lingitude = .0, altitude = .0;

memcpy(&latitude,  &buffer[ 0], sizeof(double));
memcpy(&longitude, &buffer[ 8], sizeof(double));
memcpy(&altitude,  &buffer[16], sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Lo intenté, pero el problema persiste. Sigo sin poder convertir correctamente el double al float

Comment: Cuando dices "*no puedo convertir `double` a `float`*" ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Los datos no son correctos? ¿Falla en tiempo de ejecución? ¿Falla al compilar?

Comment: Claro, no fui especifica: Recibo una trama de un INS, dicha trama la descompongo para enviarla a una consola. En la consola existen etiquetas para el muestreo de los datos recibidos. Con lo demás no tengo problema alguno, sin embargo, latitud, longitud y altitud son los únicos parámetros que me llegan en formato double. Los recibo con el buffer que puse arriba, pues van llegando por serial. Para enviar esos 3 datos a la consola, dispongo de únicamente 4B por cada uno. Al hacer el memcpy y el casteo, la consola muestra 0's en la etiqueta y de vez en cuando aparecen valores (inválidos).

Comment: Haciendo debug (utilizando la misma consola), me consta que los datos llegan bien, pues si muestro los datos recibidos sin ningún tipo de procesamiento, son un reflejo de lo que envía el dispositivo INS

Comment: ¿La consola no acepta imprimir valores `double`? No debería ser necesario hacer la conversión. Por favor, si has hecho cambios en el código desde que creaste la pregunta ¿podrías actualizar la pregunta con lo nuevo que has intentado?

Comment: La trama en la que se envían los datos del micro que estoy programando tiene la longitud fija y no la puedo modificar, por lo que debo meter la latitud exclusivamente en los 4 Bytes dedicados a ella.

Comment: Si estás usando 4 bytes... no deberías usar `float`?? `float` son 4 bytes mientras que `double` son 8. Por otro lado en el ejemplo que pones la latitud se guarda en 8 ... ¿en qué quedamos?

Comment: También si trabajas a nivel de bits, tienes que tener en cuenta las diferentes arquitecturas, big endian, little endian, ...

Comment: @eferion Lo que sucede es que el INS que manejo me entrega en double y yo precisamente quiero convertirlo a float para el manejo de solamente 4 bytes... Es little endian el formato que maneja.

Comment: @AraceliGuerrero pues entonces lee el double del INS, convierte a float y guarda dicho float en tu buffer

Answer (score 1):

> Es little endian el formato que maneja.

Mientras ambas máquinas utilicen el mismo formato no hay problema... los errores aparecen cuando una máquina es big-endian y la otra little-endian, ya que la información a nivel binario se trata de forma diferente, es decir, una secuencia de bits determinada será interpretada de forma diferente por cada equipo.

> Lo que sucede es que el INS que manejo me entrega en double y yo precisamente quiero convertirlo a float para el manejo de solamente 4 bytes...

Entonces esto:

```
uint64_t Latitude;
float data;
memcpy((u08 *)&data, (u08 *)&Latitude, sizeof(data));
INFO_GPS.Latitude.total= (s32)(data);
```

Así como cualquier código equivalente está mal. Aunque `float` y `double` sean tipos pensados para almacenar números con decimales... binariamente no son compatibles ni intercambiables. Aunque ambos tipos utilizan el mismo algoritmo para codificar los números, tienen longitudes de campos diferentes, lo que hace que la secuencia binaria que codifica un número dado difiera para cada uno de estos tipos.

Adicionalmente, fíjate que por el buffer te está llegando un `double` y tu lo estás almacenando en un `uint64_t`, es decir, un entero de 64 bits sin signo... las codificaciones de estos dos tipos son completamente diferentes!!!.

Por el buffer te llega un `double`... lo puedes leer sin problemas tal cual te ha dicho @PaperBirdMaster:

```
double latitude = .0;
memcpy(&latitude,  &buffer[ 0], sizeof(double));
```

Dado que estamos tratando datos binarios en crudo es vital respetar los tipos de datos originales, así que `latitude` **debe ser** `double`, no `uint64_t`.

Y ahora tu quieres volcarlo en formato `float` a otro buffer:

```
float latitude_float = (float)latitude;
memcpy(&data, &latitude_float, sizeof(data));
```

La primera línea fuerza una conversión de `double` a `float`. Esta conversión es necesaria porque, como te he comentado antes, a nivel binario no son tipos compatibles.

Una vez tienes el dato con el tipo adecuado simplemente lo almacenas en tu buffer y listo.

Vale, entonces lo que neceistas es leer un double, convertirlo a float y almacenar el float en tu buffer:

Comment: Muchas gracias, aún me muestra valores aleatorios, pero por lo menos son estables. Prestaré más atención al resto del procesamiento para encontrar el error. O tal vez el micro no soporte hacer operaciones así.

Comment: Haciendo debug he encontrado que, precisamente como has mencionado, la manera en la que estaba obteniendo los datos me los modificaba. Ahora que he declarado a tu manera, los datos conservan su integridad.Seguiré analizando en busca del error